# Get a matrix with absolute values in PETSc

Tags: petsc, matrix

Is there any function to create or change a matrix, to have $A_{ij} = \text{abs}(A_{ij})$ in PETSc? If possible it should work with MPIAIJ matrices, not only local.

Answer (score 1):

Though this question is about a particular functionality of an individual library, I stumbled upon the same problem some time ago.

As far as I know, there is no ready matrix function in PETSc (3.8.3) that will do it for you right out-of-the-box. I was surprised not to find a solution back a couple of years ago and now, considering the existence of such functions as:

- [`VecAbs`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Vec/VecAbs.html) that will do exactly what you want, but for vectors only
- [`MatImaginaryPart`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Mat/MatImaginaryPart.html), [`MatRealPart`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Mat/MatRealPart.html), and [`MatConjugate`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Mat/MatConjugate.html) which will perform $A_{ij}=\Re(A_{ij})$, $A_{ij}=\Im(A_{ij})$, and $A_{ij}=A^*_{ij}$, respectively.

Considering that element-wise Re, Im, and conjugation operations on matrices are supported, I would assume that all the necessary building blocks for the *MatAbs* are there, but not formally coded up.

From [`MatRealPart` subroutine source code](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/src/mat/interface/matrix.c.html#MatRealPart), the following excerpt is doing the job

```
(*mat->ops->realpart)(mat);
```

The list of supported and propagated operations on matrices is stored in [*include/petscmat.h*](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/include/petscmat.h.html) in `MatOperation` typedef. Technically, you can code up your own operation and propagate it to the datatypes you require (maybe, even by using custom user matrix `MatOperation` and `MatShellSetOperation`). However, the question is if such a development is worth the required time and pain.